# PL/SQL exception handling - log errors

Tags: oracle, plsql

How do I record the oracle error in a pl/sql script?  I have been to the oracle error handling documentation and I see the built in exceptions, but what if I do not know what the exception is?  How can I log this in an exception block?

I want to do something like the below.

```
exception
 when others then DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(the error)
```

Comment: [See the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/errors.htm#LNPLS848); but  it's usually better to only catch exceptions you can actually handle; `when others` is usually a bug. Let your client or application handle the exception, as it might not see (or know what to do with) `dbms_output` text.

Comment: Tyler Muth's open source LOGGER package is the nearest thing we have to an industry standard for logging PL/SQL. [Find it here](https://github.com/OraOpenSource/Logger) Use it, or else write your own.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to create error logging database trigger with conditional logging, for example my actual error_logging trigger: https://github.com/xtender/xt_scripts/blob/master/error_logging/on_database.sql

```html
create table ERROR_LOG
(
  id       NUMBER,
  username VARCHAR2(30),
  errcode  INTEGER,
  seq      INTEGER,
  tmstmp   TIMESTAMP(6),
  msg      VARCHAR2(4000),
  sql_text CLOB
)
/
create sequence err_seq
/
create or replace trigger trg_error_logging
after servererror
on database
disable
declare
   v_id       number   := err_seq.nextval();
   v_tmstmp   timestamp:= systimestamp;
   n          int;
   sql_text   dbms_standard.ora_name_list_t;
   v_sql_text clob;
begin
   -- only if plsql_debug is set to TRUE:
   for r in (select * from v$parameter p where p.name='plsql_debug' and upper(p.value)='TRUE') loop
       v_sql_text:=null;
       n := ora_sql_txt(sql_text);
       for i in 1..n loop
          v_sql_text := v_sql_text || sql_text(i);
       end loop;

       for i in 1.. ora_server_error_depth
       loop
          if i=1 then
             insert into error_log(id,seq,tmstmp,username,errcode,msg,sql_text)
                values( v_id, i, v_tmstmp, user, ora_server_error(i), ora_server_error_msg(i), v_sql_text);
          else
             insert into error_log(id,seq,tmstmp,username,errcode,msg)
                values( v_id, i, v_tmstmp, user, ora_server_error(i), ora_server_error_msg(i) );
          end if;
       end loop;
       commit;
    end loop;
END;
/
select object_name,object_type,status from user_objects o where object_name='TRG_ERROR_LOGGING'
/
alter trigger trg_error_logging enable
/
```

As you can see it logs all errors into the table ERROR_LOG, but only if session parameter `plsql_debug` is set to `true`. Obviously, you can change it to own parameters or conditions.